# RDS OptionGroup not working while creating it from via cloudformation for SQL Server

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to create an rds option group for RDS SQlserver independently via cloud formation while creating it is getting failed with the below error. The same when I am created with the same parameters it is able to create. Any pointers would be very helpful.

```
SqlServerOptionGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::OptionGroup
    Properties:
      EngineName: "sqlserver-ex"
      MajorEngineVersion: "14.0.0"
      OptionGroupDescription: rds-sql-optiongroup
      OptionConfigurations:
        - OptionName: SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE
```

Error:
Cannot find major version 14.0.0 for sqlserver-ex (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination

The same when I have created via console it is getting created

Answer (score 1):

Try "14.00" for `MajorEngineVersion`.

I also found you need to quote the `EngineName` and `MajorEngineVersion`, which you have done.